# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error on GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I installed FREEIPA on ubuntu 16 and set the hostname and update the /etc/hosts file as well, and Installed FREEIPA successfully but could not able to access  "https://ipa.example.com" on the browser.

Note:-
This VM is on the Google Platform and part of private DNS

error:-DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: yes. Create a private DNS and mapped. or put an entry in  /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using freeipa you are probably going to authenticate multiple machines against it.
Modifying /etc/hosts is a temporary solution that's not going to work on large environment: you need a dns server to answer when a server asks for ipa.example.com moreover you need dns to manage priority between multiple ipa servers if need high availability and resilience.